# What this Ruby does with Class.new to create class,

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Please consider the following code:

```
module MyClass
 def foo
  "method"
 end
end
```

now, I can instantiate a new class of this by usual

```
@my_new_class = MyClass.new
```

or, I can do some meta-programming magic

```
@my_new_class = Class.new { include MyClass }.send :new
```

Questions is what is the difference between the two?

Comment: You cannot do the second example: `TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)`. The keyword `include` requires a module, it would seem.

Comment: typo there.I meant a module only. nice catch.

Comment: After your edit, you cannot do the first example (`NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for MyClass:Module`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code above is (almost) equivalent to:

```
MyNewClass = Class.new { include MyClass }
@my_new_class = MyNewClass.new
```

Which is like

```
class MyNewClass
  include MyClass
end
@my_new_class = MyNewClass.new
```

using [`Class.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Class.html#method-c-new) declares an anonymous new class on the fly:

> Creates a new anonymous (unnamed) class with the given superclass (or Object if no parameter is given). You can give a class a name by assigning the class object to a constant.
>
> If a block is given, it is passed the class object, and the block is evaluated in the context of this class using `class_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Your naming of the module is akin to `sue = Boy.new`, so I've changed it to befit its heritage. I trust you won't mind.

```
module MyModule
 def foo
  "method"
 end
end
```

Let's first gather some basic information:

```
Module.class                       #=> Class
Module.ancestors                   #=> [Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Module.methods.include? :new       #=> true
Module.new                         #=> #<Module:0x000001022050c8>
```

As you see, `Module` is an instance of `Class` and has a method `:new`. Now let's look at the module you created:

```
MyModule.class                     #=> Module
MyModule.ancestors                 #=> [MyModule]
MyModule.instance_methods          #=> [:foo]
MyModule.methods.include? :new     #=> false
```

It is an instance of `Class` and has just one instance method (`:foo`), which you created. It has no ancestors, so it does not inherit any methods. Importantly, instances of `Module` do not have a method `:new`. If we try to invoke it, therefore, the results are predictable:

```
my_new_module = MyModule.new
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for MyModule:Module
```

End of story for approach #1`.

Now gather information related to your second approach:

```
my_new_instance = Class.new { include MyModule }.send :new
```

I've changed the name of the variable `my_new_class` to `my_new_instance`, for reasons that will soon become apparent.  We can write this in two steps, like this:

```
Class1 = Class.new { include MyModule }
Class1.instance_methods.include? :foo #=> true
Class1.methods.include? :new          #=> true
Class1.method(:new).owner             #=> Class
```

So we confirm `Class1` was constructed properly, has the instance method `:foo` and inherits the class method `:new` from `Class`.

```
my_new_instance = Class1.new          #=> #<Class1:0x00000101a1edc8>
my_new_instance = Class1.send :new    #=> #<Class1:0x0000010204eab8>
my_new_instance.class                 #=> Class1
my_new_instance.is_a? Class           #=> false
my_new_instance.foo                   # (prints) "method"
my_new_instance.send :foo             # (prints) "method"
```

We see that `my_new_instance` is indeed an instance of `Class1` (which can be created by either of the methods shown), and invokes `:foo` in either of the two ways shown.